# Create a sliding animation with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, gesture, sliding

I've made an app where using a slide gesture will take you from the current view to the next, however there is no animation. When you slide it just instantly replaces the screen with the new view. I want there to be a sliding animation and also want the animation to be in time with your hand as you slide across instead of just an "automatic" sliding animation if you were to swipe. Snapchat would be a good example of what I'd like to achieve, where as you slide between views the current view goes to the next. Any thing will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (built-in) thing that does what you want is a `UIPageViewController`.  This will automatically do the gesture correctly (so it's like springboard).

Comment: You probably mean `UIPageViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just swiping between `UIView` objects, consider using a `UICollectionView` where

- The cell is the size of the screen
- Turn on `pagingEnabled`
- Make it scroll horizontally

If you're swiping between `UIViewController` objects with their own respective views, you can either:

- Use `UIPageViewController`; or
- Use custom transitions with interactive animation controller (e.g. `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` tied to a pan gesture).

The page view controller is far simpler than doing custom interactive transitions.

Comment: are there any reasons why using custom UIViewController transition animations are better than using views in a page view or scroll view?  Re memory or performance. If a scroll view or page view is easier, why implement custom animations at all (trying to decide whether to redo the custom transitions in an existing app with such transitions, or if it should be rebuilt with a simpler UI setup).

Comment: Custom transitions just give you a far greater level of control, but if you're not doing anything that needs that level of control, then feel free to stick with simpler approaches. I prefer page view controller, as it's a good memory management infrastructure; if using scroll view, just be careful about memory usage (e.g. only create UI controls that are actually immediately needed, and release them as they scroll far enough away to bear any practical utility).